# comparing entries between two n x m array algorithmically

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements

I am very new to Python and my knowledge of the variety of function is very limited.

My intention is to compare each entries in an nxm array to entries in another nxm array, for all integers n,m >1. 
I'd like for Python to return another nxm array of Boolean values.

Idea:

> Entries in an array in Python is denoted by `array[i][j]` for all i in n and j in m.

Run i and j across all values in n and m, respectively. Then compare array_1[i][j] with array_2[i][j]. If array_1[i][j] == array_2[i][j] or array_1[i][j] != array_2[i][j], for some i and j in n and m, respectively, then return "True", otherwise, "False.

The result of which, boolean, is then fed into an empty array array_3.

import numpy

```
array_3 = []

array_1 = [['Roy',80,75,85,90,95],
 ['John',75,80,75,85,100],
 ['Dave',80,80,80,90,95]]

array_2 = [['Roy',80,75,75,80],
 ['John',75,60,75,75,90],
 ['Dave',50,80,70,90,85]]


print(type(array_1))
print(type(array_2))
print(type(array_3))

for array_1[i][j] in array_1:
    if array_1[i][j] == array_2[i][j]:
```

From here, I am unable to proceed further.
Any **HINTS** are appreciated.
**No solutions unless at least 24 hours from posting**

Edit:

```
import numpy

array_1 = numpy.array([['Roy',80,75,85,90,95],
 ['John',75,80,75,85,100],
 ['Dave',80,80,80,90,95]])

array_2 = numpy.array([['Roy',80,75,75,80],
 ['John',75,60,75,75,90],
 ['Dave',50,80,70,90,85]])

arrayssize = [array_1.shape, array_2.shape]
print(size)

for x in range(3):
    for y in range(5): 
        array_3 = [True if array_1[x][y] == array_2[x][y] else False]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first initialize the 3rd matrix to a relevant size.
Here is an example to initialize an array of size n with False values :

```
array_3 = [False for i in range(n)]
```

Now you should be able to initialize your array_3 but keep in mind that you have a matrix, not an array.

Then you may fill the right indexes of the matrix with True or False depending on your "if" result :

```
array_3[x][y] = comparisonResult
```

Comment: Thank you for the contribution. Let me work on this.

Comment: I'm confused with the existence of array_3. Could you explain?

Comment: array_3 would be your resulting matrix of boolean (true if array_1[x][y] == array_2[x][y] and false otherwise. Just what you wrote in your question : "The result of which, boolean, is then fed into an empty array array_3."

Comment: `import numpy

array_1 = numpy.array([['Roy',80,75,85,90,95],
     ['John',75,80,75,85,100],
     ['Dave',80,80,80,90,95]])

array_2 = numpy.array([['Roy',80,75,75,80],
     ['John',75,60,75,75,90],
     ['Dave',50,80,70,90,85]])

arrayssize = [array_1.shape, array_2.shape]
print(size)

array_3 = [True if array_1[x][y] == array_2[x][y] and False] `

Python caution me of an invalid syntax

Comment: Intuition tells me that I ought to create a separate range of values for which x and y can be indexed. 
I've made an edit to the OP. My current code provides a verification as to whether one array equals another; returns true if equal, otherwise false.
But, it still does not output a logical array